# Instances required for word2vec to learn new word

Tags: nlp, word2vec

I am new to NLP. I am learning about word2vec and trying to understand when it is useful vs not. In this case I'm trying to figure out if word2vec be useful for looking at new words/usages as they develop?
I would like to know ballpark how many instances/samples (in context) are required for a pre-trained word2vec model to learn a new word.
I have seen information on the total number of words overall required to train a model but can't find this.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most word2vec implementations use a default `min_count` of 5 - meaning they outright *discard* any words that appear fewer than 5 times as having too few usage examples, and being too rare, to be worth trying to train a vector.

So that's a good, rough floor. Every extra example, in varied realistic usage among *other* suitably-frequent words, helps. (Simply repeating the exact same text doesn't really help.)

For words that are important to my problem domain, I'd want to have dozens of contrasting usage examples.